# Why does scipy.signal.sosfilt fail when using sos value from scipy.signal.butter with order greater than 2?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am using scipy.signal to filter wav files imported with pysoundfile.  I have successfully used filtfilt to do a high pass filter with order 2 and 4 and sosfilt to high pass with order 2, but sosfilt fails when I specify order 4:

`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

I have written the below code to demonstrate the issue.

```
import soundfile
import numpy
import scipy

def butter_highpass_sosfilt(data, lowcut, fs, order=2):
    return scipy.signal.sosfilt(*scipy.signal.butter(order, [lowcut], fs=fs, btype='high', output='sos'), data)

def butter_highpass_filtfilt(data, lowcut, fs, order=1):
    return scipy.signal.filtfilt(*scipy.signal.butter(order, [lowcut], fs=fs, btype='high', output='ba'), data)

audio, samplerate = soundfile.read("Test Audio.wav") #This is 24bit 44100 PCM

output1 = numpy.zeros((numpy.size(audio[:,0]),2))
output1[:,0] = butter_highpass_filtfilt(audio[:,0], 160, samplerate, order=2)
output1[:,1] = butter_highpass_filtfilt(audio[:,1], 160, samplerate, order=2)
soundfile.write("test output 1.wav", output1, samplerate, 'PCM_24')

output2 = numpy.zeros((numpy.size(audio[:,0]),2))
output2[:,0] = butter_highpass_filtfilt(audio[:,0], 160, samplerate, order=4)
output2[:,1] = butter_highpass_filtfilt(audio[:,1], 160, samplerate, order=4)
soundfile.write("test output 2.wav", output2, samplerate, 'PCM_24')

output3 = numpy.zeros((numpy.size(audio[:,0]),2))
output3[:,0] = butter_highpass_sosfilt(audio[:,0], 160, samplerate, order=2)
output3[:,1] = butter_highpass_sosfilt(audio[:,1], 160, samplerate, order=2)
soundfile.write("test output 3.wav", output3, samplerate, 'PCM_24')

output4 = numpy.zeros((numpy.size(audio[:,0]),2))
output4[:,0] = butter_highpass_sosfilt(audio[:,0], 160, samplerate, order=4)
output4[:,1] = butter_highpass_sosfilt(audio[:,1], 160, samplerate, order=4)
soundfile.write("test output 4.wav", output4, samplerate, 'PCM_24')
```

Output1, output2, and output3 all write to wav files and play back as expected.  The program halts before writing output4 with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\Documents\Python\DSP try\Sosfilt error mre\Sosfilt error mre.py", line 29, in <module>
    output4[:,0] = butter_highpass_sosfilt(audio[:,0], 160, int(samplerate/3), order=4)
  File "M:\Documents\Python\DSP try\Sosfilt error mre\Sosfilt error mre.py", line 6, in butter_highpass_sosfilt
    return scipy.signal.sosfilt(*scipy.signal.butter(order, [lowcut], fs=fs, btype='high', output='sos'), data)
  File "C:\Users\edwar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\_signaltools.py", line 4277, in sosfilt
    x_zi_shape[axis] = 2
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: what are you doing with that `*...` there? that doesn't belong there, as far as I can remember. you just assigned the returned tuple to various arguments of that call. I am fairly sure that's not how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For order 4, `scipy.signal.butter` returns an array of shape `(2,6)`.

It's a sequence of length *two*.

When you ***unpack*** that sequence, with the `*` operator like that, into a function call, then the array's two elements (the array rows) will be scattered over the first ***and second*** parameter of the call.

All further arguments then shift "one down". *And that is the issue. The `*` for unpacking should never have been used here.*

Your `data` argument, having gotten bumped along by the unpacking, then goes in the place of the `axis` parameter of `sosfilt()`.

That axis argument expects an integer, not whatever `data` is.

The function seems to sense the "numpy-ness" of that argument, and tries to make sense of it. It might be a *zero*-dimensional `np.ndarray`? If it were, that would have been acceptable. It is not though, it has dimensions. Hence the error message:

`TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

The operative word in there is "*scalar* arrays". The "integer" is secondary here. We don't get that far into the checking.

```
np.array(42).shape == ()
```

See, that's a scalar array. If you pass that for the `axis` parameter, the function is happy (until it sees the 42, which is an outrageous axis number).

If you pass `np.array([42])` though, it throws that very same error message, because that thing has dimensions, namely one dimension of size 1. The shape is `(1,)`.

And what you passed in the position of the `axis` parameter, which is `data`, *for sure* has dimensions.

All because that innocuous unpacking `*` turned one sequence into two arguments.

---

I had to write this answer because the other answer's *explanation* is wrong. Yes, the correction is right (I suggested that `*` operator to be the issue), but that doesn't make the *explanation* right.

There is no tuple involved. There is no "single value" involved. Unpacking works on sequences of any kind. numpy arrays are sequences. `butter()` returns a numpy array. Yes, it's a single object, but here, it's also a sequence, and the unpacking operator likes sequences. That part didn't fail.

The part that *did go wrong* is the mapping of arguments to parameters, due to the unpacking.

Comment: Okay, I see what is wrong and why I missed it now.  I didn't realize that while 'ba' outputs a 2-tuple and filtfilt expects a 2-tuple, and 'sos' outputs an ndarray that looks identical in shape to a 2-tuple when order=4, sosfilt expects that ndarray to be presented as one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As Christoph correctly pointed out, the problem is with `*a_tuple` notation.

This function returns single value, not a tuple, and that breaks your code.

```
scipy.signal.butter(order, [lowcut], fs=fs, btype='high', output='sos')
```

Corrected version:

```
def butter_highpass_sosfilt(data, lowcut, fs, order=2):
    sos = scipy.signal.butter(order, [lowcut], fs=fs, btype='high', output='sos')
    return scipy.signal.sosfilt(sos, data)
```